# How to give hyperlink in the nsstring, to share in fb?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hyperlink, nsstring

`NSString` "Get the xxx iPhone App Here". In this for string "Here" , I want to give `hyperlink` to particular `URL`. Its for FB Share , and i'm using `UIActivityViewController`. I don't wanna go for `UILabel`. I know it might be silly,... help me out.

Thanks in Advance Geeks....

Comment: Did you find a solution? Tx

Answer (score 0):

If this app for IOS6 or later version in that case you can use `NSMutableAttributedString` like that. And set your custom button's frame according to `Here` string.

```
 NSString *infoString=@"Get the Solestruck iPhone App Here";

        NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:infoString];
        NSInteger _stringLength=[infoString length];

        // ------------------ Give your range for underline
        [attString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] range:NSMakeRange(_stringLength-4, 4)];

        lbl.attributedText = attString;

        [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        // ---------------- Give frame according to your text -------
//-------------------- Small change in below two line ------------
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(lbl.frame.size.width-50, 0,50, lbl.frame.size.height);
        [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [lbl addSubview:btn];

        [lbl setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

See in below image

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will try this and let u know its status. But why do i need to go for UIButton. Sharing again another image is unneccessary. Is there anything else like <a href="www.google.com"> here </a> in IOS

Comment: You need button for event and i dont know about it  <a href="www.google.com"> here </a>

Comment: The purpose is to share in FB. We are sharing already one image with message. UIbutton wont work out this case ... anyway thanks

Comment: see my edited answer you will get your answer according to me.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to share on Facebook, you need to tell Safari to open an URL which will display a Facebook page that allows the user to share. Here is an example :

```
//The url you want to share
NSString *urlString = @"http://stackoverflow.com";

//The title you want to be displayed on Facebook
NSString *title = "The Title of the Page";

//Create the URL string which will tell Facebook you want to share that specific page 
NSString *shareUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%@&t=%@", urlString , title];

//Create the URL object 
NSURL *url = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString:shareUrlString ];

//Launch Safari with the URL you created        
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

//Release the object if you don't need it
[url release];
```

Comment: Thanks Xman. But, Share is going fine , im facing issue only with providing link to NSString.

Comment: @arpit No , changed design Lol. Let me know if you find solution